# How to display Dynamic values on Images in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

[image]

I have to show name and Rating on the Page But I dont know How to do, any Suggestion or tutorial link,how to start?

Comment: I was just tried simple html method, but it was showing name in the bottom of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Images are elements used to display graphic data, you can't insert dynamic values to it, you can, through CSS, overlay them atop the image, and you'll need some javascript to dynamically change them. I strongly recommend jQuery for that.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

You can use these two to test your code more efficiently

https://jsfiddle.net/

https://codepen.io/

This guy has some pretty good video tutorial for a foundation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mp0f0zTPLec&list=PL081AC329706B2953

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```css
#image{width:100%;
height:200px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
background:#454544;
z-index:1;}

#text{
color:white;
position:absolute;
top:10px;
z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <img src="http://wallpaperwarrior.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Wallpaper-15.jpg">
<div id="text">
  <h1>some text on the image</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```